# How can I add XML declaration when I create a new file?

Tags: c#, xml, declaration, xmlwriter

I'm creating an XML file, when a determinate event occurred.

I've already try what some people answer in another similar questions, however it seems it doesn't work, because it still be missing the declaration.

This XML file contain the following elements:

```
Data
User
Number
Age
Gender
Nickname
Ability
Result
DateAndTime
```

But, I need to show the XML declaration. Like this

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

This declaration doesn't show in the file.

I'm using the following code:

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
        nombre = Code + file_count;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Data._XmlLocation + Folder + nombre + ".xml", settings);
        writer.Close();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(Data._XmlLocation + Folder + nombre + ".xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        string[] elements = { "Data", "User", "Number", "Age", "Gender", "Nickname", "Ability", "Result", "DateAndTime", };
        string[] eleValues = { "", Datos, Usuario, "", "", Number, "25", Gender, Date + " " + Hour };
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            string en = elements[i];
            string ev = eleValues[i];
            xw.WriteStartElement(en); if (ev != "")
            {
                xw.WriteString(ev); xw.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            if (eleValues[i] == "") xw.WriteEndElement();
        }
        xw.Close();
```

This code generetes a file like this:

```
<Data>
  <User/>
  <Number />
  <Age> 25 </Age>
    <Gender>
      <Nickname>
        <Ability>Continuity Test</Ability>
        <Result>FAILED</Result>
        <DateAndTime> </DateAndTime>
      </Nickname>
     </Gender> 
</Data>
```

whereas I am working for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Name>Eduardo</Name>
  <Number>24562</Number>
  <Gender>
    <Nickname>
      <Key>PASS</Key>
      <Ability>Continuity Test</Ability>
      <Result>PASSED</Result>
      <DateAndTime>2019/07/17 23:09:14:860</DateAndTime>
    </Nickname>
  </Gender>
</TestData>
```

I need to show this declaration. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to get rid of the extra `XmlTextWriter` you've declared as well as add a ConformanceLevel to the settings that marks it as a document.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document; // This is the default value, so it's not strictly necessary to set for your purposes.
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings);
```

The rest of the code is fine (once you've dropped the declaration of the XmlTextWriter)